# Having 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error trying to reach REST api from other domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, http, cross-domain

I am struggling with a following problem, I want to make a call from js (with jquery) to my remote (placed under different domain) REST api web service.

I put a proper header on the server side:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

But I am still getting error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

I am good with making an "simple request" that's mean I use only 'GET' and content type: text/plain.

As far as I know this should work with the proper header. Does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Make sure you handle OPTIONS requests on the same end-point and add the same header to the response. Browsers will perform an OPTIONS request before the GET request on cross-domain resources.

Comment: If you are making request from a site like codepen and your api's url is 'http://', it requires https:// url. Can you share more information pls?

Comment: Can you post all server side config on CORS? Besides `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, you also need `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and support OPTIONS request method.

Comment: So my CORS cod eon the server side is basically:         
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *"); 
header("ccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");                                         Do you think this should be enough ? Do i need to set some specific header on my client request ?